# Yii2 Formulario Dinámico Operaciones

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

estoy tratando de hacer operaciones en un formulario dinamico que tengo y no logro que funcione bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es que se haga la cantidad por el precio y se ponga en el importe mientras voy escribiendo, a su vez quiero que se vaya actualizando el total. Se que debería usar el evento keyup o alguno similar. Cualquier código que escribo funciona para la primer fila que es la que viene creada, si después agrego otras ya no funciona, es como si no se cargaran los eventos o algo asi. Alguna idea?
Estoy utilizando la extension de wbraganca para el formulario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pablo aquí te dejo un ejemplo que te hice. Dudo que lo puedas copiar, pegar y salga andando por que al no tener una muestra de tu código hice algo "genérico". La idea es que entiendas el funcionamiento de lo que quieres hacer y luego lo adaptes a tu código. En tu plantilla de generación de código del formulario debes realizar modificaciones mínimas y luego enfocarte en el js. Si tienes inconvenientes para adaptarlo puedes modificar la pregunta, agregar el código de tu tabla y lo vemos. Saludos!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".importe").on("input", function() {
     calcular();
});
$(".precio").on("input", function() {
     calcular();
});
$(".cantidad").on("input", function() {
     calcular();
});
});
/**
 * funcion que realiza los calculos
 */
function calcular() {

   // obtenemos todas las filas del tbody
    var filas=document.querySelectorAll("#miTabla tbody tr");
    
    var total=0;
  
    // recorremos cada una de las filas
    filas.forEach(function(e) {
        
        // obtenemos las columnas de cada fila
        var columnas=e.querySelectorAll("td input");
       
        // obtenemos los valores de la cantidad y precio
        var cantidad=parseFloat(columnas[0].value);
        
        var Precio=parseFloat(columnas[1].value);
 
        // mostramos el total por fila
        
        columnas[2].value=(cantidad*Precio).toFixed(2);
 
        //Acumulamos el importe para luego usarlo en la suma total
        total+=cantidad*Precio;
    });
 
    // mostramos la suma total
    var inputTotal=document.querySelectorAll("#miTabla tfoot tr td  input");
    inputTotal[0].value= total.toFixed(2);
  
   
    
}
```

```css
#miTabla tbody td {text-align:right;}
 #miTabla tbody td:nth-child(1) {text-align:left;}
 #miTabla th,#miTabla td  {padding:1px 10px;border:1px solid #aaa;}
  #miTabla th,#miTabla td input {width:80px}
  #miTabla th  {padding:1px 10px;border:1px solid #aaa;background-color:black; color:white}
  #inTotal{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Calcular valores de una tabla</h2>

<table id="miTabla">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th> Importe </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=3>Total</td>
            <td><input id="inTotal" type="text" value ="0.00"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>producto A</td>
            <td><input id="1" class="cantidad" value ="1" type="number"></td>
            <td><input id="2" class="precio" value ="0.00" type="number"></td>
            <td><input id="3" class="importe" value ="0.00" type="number"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>producto B</td>
                  <td><input class="cantidad" value ="1" type="number"></td>
            <td><input class="precio" value ="0.00" type="number"></td>
            <td><input class="importe" value ="0.00" type="number"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>producto C</td>
            <td><input class="cantidad" value ="1" type="number"></td>
            <td><input class="precio" value ="0.00" type="number"></td>
            <td><input class="importe" value ="0.00" type="number"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
 <h3>Fran Islas - StackOverflow ES</h3>
```

Comment: Tuve que cambiar varias cosas para adaptarlo pero logre aplicar la misma lógica y pude hacerlo funcionar, muchas gracias!.