# CÁLCULOS CON AJAX

Tags: ajax, primefaces, java-ee

Tengo problema con los cálculos en Ajax, necesito obtener la suma de los dos subtotales y mostrarlos en el cuadro TOTAL(los subtotales ya son sumas obtenidas por los números anteriores com ose muestra en la imagen).
Creo que es por el evento de AJAX que estoy usando,  utilizo keyup.
Gracias de antemano.

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:panelGrid columns="3">
            <p:inputText value="#{calculoC.calculo.nro1}">
                <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{calculoC.calcular()}" update="subtotal1"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:inputText value="#{calculoC.calculo.nro2}">
                <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{calculoC.calcular()}" update="subtotal1"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:outputLabel id="subtotal1" value="#{calculoC.calculo.subtotal1}">
                <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{calculoC.calcular()}" update="total"/>
            </p:outputLabel>
            <p:inputText value="#{calculoC.calculo.nro3}">
                <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{calculoC.calcular()}" update="subtotal2"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:inputText value="#{calculoC.calculo.nro4}">
                <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{calculoC.calcular()}" update="subtotal2"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:outputLabel id="subtotal2" value="#{calculoC.calculo.subtotal2}">
                <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{calculoC.calcular()}" update="total"/>
            </p:outputLabel>
            <br/>
            <p:outputLabel value="TOTAL:"/>
            <p:inputText id="total" value="#{calculoC.calculo.total}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

controlador:

```
CalculoM calculo = new CalculoM();

public void calcular(){
    getCalculo().setSubtotal1(getCalculo().getNro1() + getCalculo().getNro2());
    getCalculo().setSubtotal2(getCalculo().getNro3() + getCalculo().getNro4());

    getCalculo().setTotal(getCalculo().getSubtotal1() + getCalculo().getSubtotal2());
}

public CalculoM getCalculo() {
    return calculo;
}

public void setCalculo(CalculoM calculo) {
    this.calculo = calculo;
}
```

imagen:
[image: VISTA]

Comment: Hola bro, re recomiento que pongas el codigo que llevas hasta ahora, asi sera mas facil para lo que queremos ayudarte a solucionar el problema basados en tu logica, ademas indicar en que momento se deben mostrar el total

Comment: Gracias por responder. Quiero mostrar el total al mismo momento en que los resultados de los subtotales se muestran, ya subí el código.

Comment: el código javascript no está, deberías mostrarlo tambien.

Comment: Lo hago desde el controlador.

Comment: No has considerado hacer los cálculos en el cliente con js? Si te interesa te dejo un link [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206336/yii2-formulario-din%C3%A1mico-operaciones/206411#206411) donde otro usuario necesita hacer prácticamente lo mismo. En la respuesta le dejo un ejemplo para que lo pruebe. Saludos

Comment: Debes aprender javascript ya que cosas tan simples muy raramente deberían ejecutarse en el servidor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con Jquery es bastanta facil, quizas te pueda servir este, ya que es netamente funcional.

```js
 function sumar(opcion){
    if (opcion==1) {
      var suma =   parseInt($('#valor1').val()) +  parseInt($('#valor2').val());
      $('#Subtotal1').val(suma);
      var suma2 =   parseInt($('#Subtotal1').val()) +  parseInt($('#Subtotal2').val());
      $('#Total').val(suma2);
    }else if (opcion == 2) {
      var suma1 =   parseInt($('#valor3').val()) +  parseInt($('#valor4').val());
      $('#Subtotal2').val(suma1);
      var suma3 =   parseInt($('#Subtotal1').val()) +  parseInt($('#Subtotal2').val());
      $('#Total').val(suma3);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12 input-group">
      <label for="valor1" class="form-label col-lg-3">Valor 1</label>
      <input type="number" name="valor1" id="valor1" class="form-input col-lg-1" value="0" onchange="sumar(1);">
      <label for="valor2" class="form-label col-lg-3">Valor 2</label>
      <input type="number" name="valor2" id="valor2" class="form-input col-lg-1" value="0" onchange="sumar(1);">
      <label for="Subtotal1" class="form-label col-lg-3">Subtotal1 1</label>
      <input type="number" name="Subtotal1" id="Subtotal1" class="form-input col-lg-1" value="0" onchange="sumar(3);">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 input-group">
      <label for="valor3" class="form-label col-lg-3">Valor 3</label>
      <input type="number" name="valor3" id="valor3" class="form-input col-lg-1" value="0" onchange="sumar(2);">
      <label for="valor4" class="form-label col-lg-3">Valor 4</label>
      <input type="number" name="valor4" id="valor4" class="form-input col-lg-1" value="0" onchange="sumar(2);">
      <label for="Subtotal2" class="form-label col-lg-3">Subtotal2 2</label>
      <input type="number" name="Subtotal2" id="Subtotal2" class="form-input col-lg-1" value="0" onchange="sumar(3);">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 offset-8 input-group">
      <label for="Total" class="form-label col-lg-3">Total</label>
      <input type="number" name="Total" id="Total" class="form-input col-lg-1" value="0" >
    </div>
```

de esta forma quedaria lo que necesitas... ya esta en ti darle los estilos y acomodarlos como te guste.

espero te sirve, me cuentas como te fue